# How to listen and subscribe to HTTP events with NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, http, axios

I am trying to create an invoice, then track its status by subscribing to events. I am using the bitpay REST API for this, and I have already successfully created the invoice and successfully retrieving the bus token.

This is what the [bitpay docs](https://test.bitpay.com/api/#rest-api-resources-invoices-retrieve-an-event-token-for-an-invoice) says:

```
Once you have retrieved the bus pass, It's pretty simple. Send a GET request to the path configured for the bus - let's say it's bitpay.com/events including the appropriate parameters:

?token= - your "bus pass" retrieved from the API
&action= - usually "subscribe", but options are provided in your bus pass
&events[]= - an array of events to listen for (also provided in the bus pass)
Once you've opened the connection, you'll want to listen for chunks of data to be passed to you. Each chunk represents an event. Since the bus adheres to the SSE/EventSource specification, chunks are passed back in the format:

event: <event_type>

data: {"some":"json"}
```

How do I listen to these events? When I click into the link that I am trying to listen to, this is what I see:

```
:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
retry: 2000
event: connect
data: {"status":"subscribed","resource":"Sg9hggVxgC1VTKsGYqNyVT","facade":"public/invoice","events":["payment","confirmation","paymentRejected","scanned","paymentPosted"]}

event: state
data: {"url":"https://test.bitpay.com/invoice?
...
```

Herre is what I have tried:

```
const evtSource = new EventSource('<path>');

evtSource.onmessage = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
}
```

and

```
axios({
    url : '<path>',
    method: 'get',
    connect: function(event){
        console.log(event);
    }
})
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Here is an example [link](https://test.bitpay.com/events?token=767cdhmwtn7XgW1QrSkuEwoYea8TVZmkK8XZxJPjKiVFiqMuYL1rnXMDmK964Euds3&action=subscribe&events%5B%5D=payment&events%5B%5D=confirmation&events%5B%5D=paymentRejected&events%5B%5D=scanned&events%5B%5D=paymentPosted) for what I want to listen from.

Comment: You have to wait for the callback lke this:

axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example Codesandbox demo https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-borg-365z2?file=/app.js:0-496

```
const EventSource = require("eventsource");
const eventSourceInitDict = { https: { rejectUnauthorized: false } };

const evtSource = new EventSource(
  "https://test.bitpay.com/events?token=767cdhmwtn7XgW1QrSkuEweXC3dUyCRcZqwvcGRvSeaDZh8UXj9aCcS1xPPppjaFYH&action=subscribe&events[]=payment&events[]=confirmation&events[]=paymentRejected&events[]=scanned&events[]=paymentPosted",
  eventSourceInitDict
);

evtSource.addEventListener("connect", function (e) {
  console.log("connect", e.data);
});


LOGS: connect {"status":"subscribed","resource":"HZxbCd5YRWnWJ4kK72DBai","facade":"public/invoice","events":["payment","confirmation","paymentRejected","scanned","paymentPosted"]
```

So I'm guessing after connect event you can subscribe to the other events like this:

```
evtSource.addEventListener("payment", function (e) {
  console.log("payment", e.data);
});
```

Try instead of:

```
const evtSource = new EventSource('<path>');
evtSource.onmessage = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Updated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource

```
  const sse = new EventSource('<path>');
  sse.addEventListener('<event>', function(e) { 
    console.log(e.data)
  });
```

Comment: I had already tried this. It is not calling any of my .then or .catch functions. It might also be useful if I provide an example link: `https://test.bitpay.com/events?token=767cdhmwtn7XgW1QrSkuEwoYea8TVZmkK8XZxJPjKiVFiqMuYL1rnXMDmK964Euds3&action=subscribe&events[]=payment&events[]=confirmation&events[]=paymentRejected&events[]=scanned&events[]=paymentPosted`

Comment: I know how to make regular GET requests. Its just that I have no idea how to subscribe and listen to the events. If you click into the link I provided, you can see events like connect or state. I want to pass in callbacks that gets called when those events happen.

Comment: Your node server may need to have a route to listen to those events like app.get('/events', eventsHandler);
Those events are server side sent events, you need a server listening for those. Simply calling axios wont work.


https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: These may help https://github.com/EventSource/eventsource

Comment: what did I do wrong in my attempt? I was using the same module, as you can see in my question.

Comment: I hard to tell without all the code available to debug, can you provide a gist or codesandbox?

Comment: Updated the solution with a working example @Eden with a sample codesandbox

Comment: I was stupid to assume that all events will call the sse.onmessage function